# How can I assert hasProperty with a Java Record?

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest, java-record, java-16

I have a piece of code in a test that checks that a list of results contains certain properties, using Hamcrest 2.2:

```
assertThat(result.getUsers(), hasItem(
    hasProperty("name", equalTo(user1.getName()))
));
assertThat(result.getUsers(), hasItem(
    hasProperty("name", equalTo(user2.getName()))
));
```

This worked perfectly fine when `NameDto` was a normal class. But after I changed it to a `Record`, Hamcrest's `hasProperty` complains about there being no property named `name`:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: a collection containing hasProperty("name", "Test Name")
     but: mismatches were: [No property "name", No property "name"]
```

Is there some other matcher I can use to achieve the same matching as before? Or some other workaround I can use to get it to work with records?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The accessor method of a record field does not follow the regular JavaBeans convention, so the `User` record (say `public record User (String name) {}`) will have an accessor method whose name is `name()` instead of `getName()`.

I suspect this is why Hamcrest considers there is no property. I don't think there is a way out-of-the-box in Hamcrest other than to write a custom Matcher.

Here's a custom `HasRecordComponentWithValue` inspired by the existing [`HasPropertyWithValue`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/HasPropertyWithValue.html). The main utility leveraged here is Java's [`Class.getRecordComponents()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getRecordComponents()):

```
public static class HasRecordComponentWithValue<T> extends TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<T> {
    private static final Condition.Step<RecordComponent,Method> WITH_READ_METHOD = withReadMethod();
    private final String componentName;
    private final Matcher<Object> valueMatcher;

    public HasRecordComponentWithValue(String componentName, Matcher<?> valueMatcher) {
        this.componentName = componentName;
        this.valueMatcher = nastyGenericsWorkaround(valueMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matchesSafely(T bean, Description mismatch) {
        return recordComponentOn(bean, mismatch)
                  .and(WITH_READ_METHOD)
                  .and(withPropertyValue(bean))
                  .matching(valueMatcher, "record component'" + componentName + "' ");
    }

    private Condition.Step<Method, Object> withPropertyValue(final T bean) {
        return new Condition.Step<Method, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Condition<Object> apply(Method readMethod, Description mismatch) {
                try {
                    return matched(readMethod.invoke(bean, NO_ARGUMENTS), mismatch);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    mismatch.appendText(e.getMessage());
                    return notMatched();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("hasRecordComponent(").appendValue(componentName).appendText(", ")
                   .appendDescriptionOf(valueMatcher).appendText(")");
    }

    private Condition<RecordComponent> recordComponentOn(T bean, Description mismatch) {
        RecordComponent[] recordComponents = bean.getClass().getRecordComponents();
        for(RecordComponent comp : recordComponents) {
            if(comp.getName().equals(componentName)) {
                return matched(comp, mismatch);
            }
        }
        mismatch.appendText("No record component \"" + componentName + "\"");
        return notMatched();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Matcher<Object> nastyGenericsWorkaround(Matcher<?> valueMatcher) {
        return (Matcher<Object>) valueMatcher;
    }

    private static Condition.Step<RecordComponent,Method> withReadMethod() {
        return new Condition.Step<RecordComponent, java.lang.reflect.Method>() {
            @Override
            public Condition<Method> apply(RecordComponent property, Description mismatch) {
                final Method readMethod = property.getAccessor();
                if (null == readMethod) {
                    mismatch.appendText("record component \"" + property.getName() + "\" is not readable");
                    return notMatched();
                }
                return matched(readMethod, mismatch);
            }
        };
    }

    @Factory
    public static <T> Matcher<T> hasRecordComponent(String componentName, Matcher<?> valueMatcher) {
        return new HasRecordComponentWithValue<T>(componentName, valueMatcher);
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice, but I guess Hamcrest could "fix" this and internally check if that is a `record` via `Class::isRecord`

Comment: @Eugene Agreed 100%, although I'm not sure they are compatible with recent versions of Java.

Comment: @Eugene or Java Beans gets updated to catch up with its own Java version. Unless the Java designers say that record components are not properties (in which case Hamcrest would be right).

Comment: A number of frameworks have already upgraded to support records; most have found this to be a very small amount of code.  I suspect a polite request to the Hamcrest maintainers would result in this addition.

Comment: I now submitted an issue in Hamcrest to point out this problem: https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/392

Answer (score 5):

I found that the same test can be achieved using *only* AssertJ, at least in this case:

```
assertThat(result.getUsers())
        .extracting(UserDto::name)
        .contains(user1.getName(), user2.getName());
```

It's not using `hasProperty`, so it doesn't exactly solve the question though.

Answer (score 2):

Hamcrest actually follows the JavaBeans standard (which allows for arbitrary accessor names), so we *can* do this with `hasProperty`. If you want to. I'm not sure you do, though - it's quite a hassle.

If we follow the workings of [the source for `HasPropertyWithValue`](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/beans/HasPropertyWithValue.java) we find that it discovers the accessor method's name by finding the [`PropertyDescriptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) for the property in the [`BeanInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) of the class concerned, retrieved by means of the [`java.beans.Introspector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Introspector.html).

The `Introspector` has some very helpful documentation on how `BeanInfo` for a given class is resolved:

> The Introspector class provides a standard way for tools to learn
> about the properties, events, and methods supported by a target Java
> Bean.
>
> For each of those three kinds of information, the Introspector will
> separately analyze the bean's class and superclasses looking for
> either explicit or implicit information and use that information to
> build a BeanInfo object that comprehensively describes the target
> bean.
>
> For each class "Foo", explicit information may be available if there
> exists a corresponding "FooBeanInfo" class that provides a non-null
> value when queried for the information. We first look for the BeanInfo
> class by taking the full package-qualified name of the target bean
> class and appending "BeanInfo" to form a new class name. If this
> fails, then we take the final classname component of this name, and
> look for that class in each of the packages specified in the BeanInfo
> package search path.
>
> Thus for a class such as "sun.xyz.OurButton" we would first look for a
> BeanInfo class called "sun.xyz.OurButtonBeanInfo" and if that failed
> we'd look in each package in the BeanInfo search path for an
> OurButtonBeanInfo class. With the default search path, this would mean
> looking for "sun.beans.infos.OurButtonBeanInfo".
>
> If a class provides explicit BeanInfo about itself then we add that to
> the BeanInfo information we obtained from analyzing any derived
> classes, but we regard the explicit information as being definitive
> for the current class and its base classes, and do not proceed any
> further up the superclass chain.
>
> If we don't find explicit BeanInfo on a class, we use low-level
> reflection to study the methods of the class and apply standard design
> patterns to identify property accessors, event sources, or public
> methods. We then proceed to analyze the class's superclass and add in
> the information from it (and possibly on up the superclass chain).

You'd think the `Introspector` could grok records and generate correct `BeanInfo` in that last step (where "we use low-level reflection"), but it appears not to. If you google for a bit you'll find some talk on the JDK dev list about adding this, but nothing seems to have happened. Might be that the JavaBeans spec has to be updated, which I imagine could take some time.

But, to answer your question, all we have to do is provide a `BeanInfo` for each and every record type you have. Handwriting them, however, isn't something we want to do - it's even worse than the old-fashioned way of writing classes with getters and setters (and `equals` and `hashCode` and whatnot).

We could autogenerate the bean info as a build step (or dynamically when we start the app). A somewhat simpler approach (which requires a bit of boilerplate) is making a generic `BeanInfo` that can be used for all record classes. Here's a minimum-effort approach. First, suppose we have this record:

```java
public record Point(int x, int y){}
```

And a main class that treats it as a bean:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var bi = java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Point.class);
        var bean = new Point(4, 2);
        for (var prop : args) {
            Object value = Stream.of(bi.getPropertyDescriptors())
                .filter(pd -> pd.getName().equals(prop))
                .findAny()
                .map(pd -> {
                    try {
                        return pd.getReadMethod().invoke(bean);
                    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                        return "Error: " + e;
                    }
                })
                .orElse("(No property with that name)");
            System.out.printf("Prop %s: %s%n", prop, value);
        }
    }
}
```

If we just compile and run like `java Main x y z` you get output like this:

```
Prop x: (No property with that name)
Prop y: (No property with that name)
Prop z: (No property with that name)
```

So it doesn't find the record components, as expected. Let's make a generic `BeanInfo`:

```java
public abstract class RecordBeanInfo extends java.beans.SimpleBeanInfo {

    private final PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors;

    public RecordBeanInfo(Class<?> recordClass) throws IntrospectionException {
        if (!recordClass.isRecord())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a record: " + recordClass);
        var components = recordClass.getRecordComponents();
        propertyDescriptors = new PropertyDescriptor[components.length];
        for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            var c = components[i];
            propertyDescriptors[i] = new PropertyDescriptor(c.getName(), c.getAccessor(), null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
        return this.propertyDescriptors.clone();
    }

}
```

Having this class in our toolbox, all we have to do is extend it with a class of the right name. For our example, `PointBeanInfo` in the same package as the `Point` record:

```java
public class PointBeanInfo extends RecordBeanInfo {
    public PointBeanInfo() throws IntrospectionException {
        super(Point.class);
    }
}
```

With all these things in place, we run our main class and get the expected output:

```
$ java Main x y z
Prop x: 4
Prop y: 2
Prop z: (No property with that name)
```

Closing note: If you just want to use properties to make your unit tests look nicer, I suggest using one of the workarounds given in other answers, rather than the overengineered approach I present.